# Vuetify in Storybook gets error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$vuetify.theme.dark')

Tags: vuetify.js, storybook

I'm trying to use Vuetify in Storybook with costume setup. The .Storybook/config.js looks like:

```
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/vue';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
      dark: {
        primaryTypColor: '#232B2B',
        productCardTitle: '#7E7F80'
      },
      light: {
        primaryTypColor: '#232B2B',
        productCardTitle: '#7E7F80'
      },

   },
});

addDecorator(() => ({
 template: '<v-app><story/></v-app>',
}));

configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

I'm getting the error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$vuetify.theme.dark') why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't injected the global `vuetify` object in the Vue.js context. You can do so with a decorator.

In your example it looks like you only need to add the `Vuetify` that you imported to the `addDecorator` function as a parameter.

A complete example for storybook versions below 6, here is how:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from '@plugins/vuetify'

Vue.use(vuetify)

addDecorator(() => ({
 template: '<v-app><story/></v-app>',
 vuetify,
}));
```

For storybook version 6:

```
import vuetify from '@plugins/vuetify'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(vuetify)

export const decorators = [
  () => ({
    template: '<v-app><story/></v-app>',
    vuetify
  }),
]
```